# запрос списка друзей с VK swift

Tags: swift, vkontakte-api, swift4

Добрый день никак не получается на swift сформировать запрос списка друзей(имя пользователя и аватарка) c VK и потом грамотно передать его в tableView(

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON

class Friend {
    var friendFirstName:String = ""
    var friendLastName:String = ""
    var friendImage:String = ""


}


class FriendsTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    var friends = [Friend]()



let thisToken = theGlobalToken!

let theURL = "https://api.vk.com/method/friends.get?access_token=\(theGlobalToken!)&fields=picture_50&lang=ru&count=100&version=5.69&"

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    getFriends()


}




override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

}



override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    return friends.count
}


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! FriendsCellTableViewCell
    let friend = friends[indexPath.row]

    cell.Name?.text = friends[indexPath.row].friendLastName+friends[indexPath.row].friendLastName
   // cell.Avatar.image = friends[indexPath.row].friendImage
    return cell
}

func getFriends() {
    let request = URLRequest(url:URL(string:theURL)!)
    let urlSession = URLSession.shared
    let task = urlSession.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) -> Void in
        if let error = error {
            print (error)
            return }
        if let data = data {

            self.friends = self.parseJsonData(data: data)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.tableView.reloadData()                }


        }
    }

    task.resume()



}
func parseJsonData(data:Data)->[Friend]{
    do {            let jsonresult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as? NSDictionary
        let jsonTotal = jsonresult?["response"] as? [AnyObject]
        let jsonFriends = jsonTotal["items"] as! [AnyObject]
        for jsonFriend in jsonFriends {
            let friend = Friend()


            friend.friendFirstName = jsonFriend["first_name"] as! String
            friend.friendLastName = jsonFriend["last_name"] as! String
           // friend.friendImage = jsonFriend["photo_50"] as! UIImage
            friends.append(friend)




        }

    }catch {
        print(error)
    }
    return friends

}
```

}

Comment: Добавьте пример кода, того, как вы пытаетесь сделать, если есть текст ошибки, которая у вас появляется, то и ее добавьте. На данный момент не понятно, что и как вы пытаетесь сделать.

Comment: Спасибо, добавил код. Не получается грамотно распарсить и создать переменную для обработки получаемого изображения.